# SVG <rect> with text and div fill width with transition

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I'm working on an SVG here I want a rectangle to add text inside div and color fill with transition I had tried like this

```
<g>
  <rect width="25%" height="100%" fill="blue"></rect>
  <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="none"></rect>
  <text x="0" y="50"  font-size="35" fill="green">text here</text>
</g>
```

Still not coming and for the animation i tried like this

```
<animate attributeName="width" from="0" to="200" dur="5s" />
```

Can anyone suggest to me how to achieve this output. Any help will be appreciate

```css
svg {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="slider1" type="range" min="0" max="100" step="25" value="25" oninput="document.querySelector(`#SVG${this.id} rect`).setAttribute('width',this.value+'%')" />

<svg id="SVGslider1" viewBox="0 0 30 6">
  <rect width="25%" height="100%" fill="blue" />
  <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="none" stroke="black"/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adjusting `x`, `y` and `font-size` on the text and adding a `transition` property for the `rect`:

```css
svg {
  width: 200px;
}

rect {
  transition: width 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="slider1" type="range" min="0" max="100" step="25" value="25" oninput="document.querySelector(`#SVG${this.id} rect`).setAttribute('width',this.value+'%')" />

<svg id="SVGslider1" viewBox="0 0 30 6">
  <rect width="25%" height="100%" fill="blue" />
  <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="none" stroke="black"/>
  <text x="5" y="5"  font-size="6" fill="green">text here</text>
</svg>
```

EDIT: to make the `<rect>` element fill vertically, swap `width` for `height` and `y`:

```css
svg {
  width: 200px;
}

rect {
  transition: y 0.5s, height 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="slider1" type="range" min="0" max="100" step="25" value="25" oninput="document.querySelector(`#SVG${this.id} rect`).setAttribute('height',this.value+'%');document.querySelector(`#SVG${this.id} rect`).setAttribute('y',100-this.value+'%')" />

<svg id="SVGslider1" viewBox="0 0 30 6">
  <rect y="75%" width="100%" height="25%" fill="blue" />
  <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="none" stroke="black"/>
  <text x="5" y="5"  font-size="6" fill="green">text here</text>
</svg>
```